# Flask-security defaults to MongoDB

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I have an app with `Flask security`. It uses `SQLAlchemy` and `MongoDB` (pymongo)
I have this configured but when a DB interfering appears (from another app that also uses `flask`) I have the `flask-security` defaulting to `MongoDB` gear instead of `SQLAlchemy`.

Main question if this somehow could be explicitly set. 
E.g. Go use `SQLAlchemy` and not `MongoDB` for storing your user data...

```
# config.py
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/somedb'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://login:password@127.0.0.1/mydb'
```

How to determine on run time which to use or how to set to one or the other?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you mean that you'd like to determine on run time which to use or how to set to one or the other?

Comment: Exactly. This is what I have meant. Updated question. Thank you!

Comment: `if YOUR_CONDITION:
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
else:
    user_datastore = MongoEngineUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)` ...